# How to define format for textbox

Tags: c#, formatting

I have text box for IP address . When the text box is displayed I want ti to have dots like "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" where xxx are blank by default so the user enters the IP address correctly.

Comment: WPF or WinForms? You seem to be looking for a MaskedTextBox.

Comment: MaskedTextBox could be your starting point, but the validation of the input text is cumbersome. Better to look for pre-made custom control like [this on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4693/IP-Address-TextBox) NO warranty...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do not want to validate this while the user is enering the IP but after he is done with it.

Check Control.Validating Event for that.

what you can do:

```
public void textBox_Validating()
{
    Regex reg = new Regex("^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$");
    bool valide = reg.IsMatch(textBox.Text);
    //do whatever you want if it is not an ip (valide == false)
}
```